# Time Interval between keydown and keyup events RXJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, keydown

I want to get the timeInterval between keydown and keyup events for a each key pressed

```
var keyDowns = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keydown");
var keyUps = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keyup");

var keyPresses = keyDowns.merge(keyUps)
   //group by keycode, ie '87'= w
  .groupBy(e => e.keyCode)
   //map distinct keydowns and keyups - ideally, would want to get timeInterval after this
  .map(group => group.distinctUntilChanged(null, e => e.type))
   //flatten observable of key events observables
  .mergeAll()

keyPresses.subscribe(function(e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.key);
    //console.log(e)
});

input: hold w, release w
output: keydown w
        keyup w
```

I want to map these to an object structured like this

```
intervals = {'w-key': {
               'press1': 1000ms
               'press2': 1123ms
             }
             'd-key': {
               'press1': 402ms
             }
            }
```

Haalp please?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of this? After distinctUntilChanged we pair the value with the previous one using `pairwise` and then map them back into one with a new field, the measured `duration` of time between the successive emits. To get the very first value that does not have a predecessor, we need to `startWith` a dummy value `{timeStamp:undefined}`.

```
import { fromEvent, merge } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/rxjs@^6.6.7?min';
import { 
    groupBy, 
    map, 
    distinctUntilChanged, 
    mergeAll,
    pairwise,
    startWith } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/rxjs@^6.6.7/operators?min';

const keyPresses = merge(
  fromEvent(window, 'keydown', {capture: true}),
  fromEvent(window, 'keyup', {capture: true}),
).pipe(
  groupBy(e => e.code),
  map(group => group.pipe(
    startWith({timeStamp:undefined}),
    distinctUntilChanged(null, e=>e.type), 
    pairwise(),
    map(([e0,e1])=>Object.assign(e1,{duration:e1.timeStamp-e0.timeStamp})))),
  mergeAll(),
);

keyPresses.subscribe(e=> {
  console.log(JSON.stringify({code:e.code, type:e.type, duration:e.duration}));
});
```

https://codepen.io/codepen0980/pen/dyNBwpd

Answer (score 0):

I think `withLatestFrom` is the operator that will help you here. This will give you something very close to what you are looking for:

```
const down = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keydown")
    .distinctUntilKeyChanged("keyCode");

const up = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keyup");

up.withLatestFrom(down, (u, d) => ({
    name: `${String.fromCharCode(d.keyCode)}-key`,
    pressTime: u.timeStamp - d.timeStamp
}))
    .groupBy(x => x.name)
    .mergeMap(group => group.scan((acc, x) => {
        acc[group.key].push(x.pressTime);
        return acc;
    }, {[group.key]: []}))
    .scan((acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, x))
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: This solution has been helpful but I can't seem to resolve some issues with it. 
withLatestFrom is being passed  'down' events for both u and d. Because of this getting weird pressTime: timestamps. The pressTime is more or less accurate for first up/down event, but afterwards it keeps running on and after a while i get presstimes in the millions of ms, even after pressing up/down in quick succession.